# Changing Query Layer's SQL Expression with Python

Tags: arcpy, layers, sql, query, arcgis-10.4

I use query layers in ArcMap 10.4. The maps need to be done/repeated periodically. The easiest way is to copy the map, change the source's SQL expression (e.g. from **select * from TABLE where Period = '2016-March'** to **select * from TABLE where Period = '2016-April'**) and that's it. But the expressions are long and hard to edit. Then I have many similar maps, where I have to make edits manually.

**Is there a way to do this with Python?**

Using the combination of query layer and definition query is not doable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to do this in python. Check out the documentation on the Make Query Layer tool http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-layer.htm

You can also use the make query table tool (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-table.htm); if you specify a shape field the query table becomes a query layer.

If the expression is all that needs to be edited, you can type the expression out and use Python's `.format()` to pass in whatever changes you want to make (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Like this:

```
date = '2016-April'
expression = "select * from TABLE where Period = '{}'".format(date)
```

You can even automate the updated date for your input

```
import datetime
import calendar

current_month_year = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('-')[:2]
date = "{}-{}".format(current_month_year[0], calendar.month_name[int(current_month_year[1])])
expression = "select * from TABLE where Period = '{}'".format(date)
```

Which gives the result: `"select * from TABLE where Period = '2016-April'"`

calendar: https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name

datetime: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

If you use `arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management()` to create your query layer, use `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management()` to save it as a feature class/shapefile.

EDIT: Arcpy also has tools for total map production (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/getting-started-with-arcpy-mp-tutorial.htm) in python. If your map-making procedure involves changing one layer, adding it to a template with other feature classes/shapefiles, and exporting as a pdf, all of these things can be done in python.

Googling "creating a map with arcpy in python" yields a lot of good resources to help you get started (https://www.google.com/#q=creating+a+map+with+arcpy+in+python)

Comment: Since you are already using `datetime`, no need to work with strings at all: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%B")`

Comment: I'll take a look at this.   However in my case, and I should've been more specific, Periods are the text fields, rather than Date/Time. I was thinking more in terms of (if possible) **QLayer.SourceQuery.Replace("OldText","NewText")**